# Trocando Value Object no banco de dados

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd, projeto-de-software

Estou lendo o livro de DDD (Eric Evans) que diz as implementações de **Value Object** são imutáveis e se quiser mudá-lo, você terá que criar um outro. Em exemplos mais comuns onde tem uma classe `Pessoa` e outra classe `Endereco`, você recriar o endereço ao invés de alterar o objeto, isto funciona ok.

E li também https://cargotracker.java.net/ e https://gojko.net/2009/09/30/ddd-and-relational-databases-the-value-object-dilemma/. Mas eu tenho algo um pouco diferente que surgiram dúvidas.

Eu estou trabalhando num sistema de billing, e contém 4 tabelas

```
Pessoa - campos: idPessoa, Nome -> <<Entity>>
Celular - campos: idCelular, Numero -> <<Entity>>
Vigencia - campos: idVigencia, idPessoa, idCelular, dataInicio, dataFim -> <<Value Object ou Entity????>>
```

A tabela Pessoa seria o cadastro de funcionário da empresa, suponhamos que tenha em torno de 10 mil registros
A tabela Celular são dados de todos celulares que a empresa possui, suponhamos uns 3 mil registros

A tabela Vigencia é a associativa de Pessoa X Celular, exemplo, o "Joao" está com o celular "11 91234-5678" na data inicial "01-01-2016" e a data final ficaria nula significando que ainda este celular está com ele, e este registro teria um "idVigencia" 1, que não é relativo ao negócio.

Agora que estamos no dia 20/08/2016, ficamos sabendo que o "João" não é mais dono deste celular, e agora é a Maria. Então na tabela de "Vigencia" atualizaria a "data final" da vigencia do "João" para "31-07-2016" e criaria outro registro para a "Maria" com a "data inicia" em "01-08-2016", assim diz que o celular "trocou" de dono

```
Ligacao - campos: idLigacao, idVigencia, etc... -> <<Value Object>>
```

Na tabela de ligações, temos ligações do mes 05, 06, 07 e 08 de 2016, onde este celular está com o João, então a FK do campo idVigencia da tabela de Ligação será o numero 1 neste caso, só que com a mudança da "Vigencia" do "João" o mês 08/2016 estaria com a FK errada e deveria ser reprocessada.

Sendo assim, a "Vigencia" seria um Value Object ? (que também é minha duvida, pois poderia talvez ser um Entity, porém não vejo uma identidade no "idVigencia", talvez no conjunto de campos)

Caso for um <> a vigencia seria imutável e ao atualizar o "João" colocando a "data final" para "31-07-2016", teria que descartar o objeto e criá-lo novamente, só que entra no problema em relação a FK "idVigencia" da tabela de "Ligação"

Qual a melhor maneira de implementar isso com DDD?

Comment: Existe relação entre `idPeriodo` e `idVingencia`, é isso?

Comment: Vale lembrar que a abordagem, ou mesmo a arquitetura em si, deve servir a necessidade do seu projeto, e não o contrário. Você tem um fluxograma tipo "guardanapo de restaurante"? Comece simples, faça as ferramentas trabalharem pra você ;-)

Comment: @MarcoAurelio Obrigado pela resposta. Acredito que faltou dados na pergunta. Colocarei numa resposta abaixo para ficar mais clara as informações, toda ajuda é bem vinda, peguei esse problema como exemplo mesmo

Comment: Conforme mencionado, um Value Object não se altera. E, ao contrário do que também está mencionado na pergunta, não há como "mudá-lo". Se, em algum cenário, algum valor deve mudar, e tal mudança é natural, então isto indica que não se trata de um Value Object.

Answer (score 0):

É um típico problema de se criar **Value Object** estruturados em bases relacionais. Começa-se a criar ID para o VO, por necessidade, mesmo sabendo que um VO não possui ID por definição.

Para realmente ajudar a resolver seu problema, eu precisaria conhecer mais do negócio. Mas o pouco que você passou, vou arriscar o seguinte:

- Caso seja removido o `idPeriodo` - que eu imagino que seja o FK para `Vigência`, seu problema está resolvido

E, para relacionar as ligações com a vigência, poderá usar apenas as datas. Assim fica-se livre para manter as datas ou qualquer outra propriedade de Vigência, sem precisar recriar todas as ligações.

Para pesquisar as ligações em uma vigência, pode-se usar o `idCelular` mais das datas. Acredito que será performático o suficiente.

Comment: alterei a pergunta colocando mais detalhes sobre o negócio, a data da ligação acredito que com o volume extremamente alto, poderá ter impacto em performance :( . Espero ter conseguido melhorar minha pergunta acima que editei

Answer (score 0):

## DDD é para o domínio, tabelas é para a persistência

O seu modelo OO rico provavelmente possui a classe *Pessoa*, *Vigência* e *Telefone*. Acredito que em *Vigência* há uma referência para *Pessoa* e outra para *Telefone*, além dos demais atributos. Quando se trata de um *Value Object* os atributos não podem ser alterados (pois isto é da natureza de um *Value Object*), o que não é o caso com *Vigência*. Então, *Vigência* não é um *Value Object*, pois você pode estender a data final, o que é natural para uma vigência, mas não faz sentido em um *Value Object*.

Quando se pensa em um Value Object V com o atributo x com um dado valor, se houver possibilidade de x possuir ou assumir outro valor diferente daquele de V, então se trata de outro objeto, não é o mesmo.

Por fim, DDD visa refletir com fidelidade um domínio, enquanto tabelas tem como foco a persistência, o que são tópicos distintos e, muitas vezes, conflitantes. Persistir um modelo OO rico, em geral, usando o modelo relacional, introduz vários desafios. A incompatibilidade entre estes modelos é conhecida por *impedance mismatch* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Se você evitar os desafios, provavelmente está abrindo mão do modelo OO, porque seu banco relacional não irá deixar de ser relacional.